# How to pass a value from Node.js server to an embedded Javascript code inside HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm working on this project in which i need to pass a data brought from Mysql database via Node js server to HTML page that has embedded Javascript code to use this data to draw a chart by using Chart.js library.
This is the node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var plotly = require('plotly')("qzzaz111", "ivonjyk1gd")


var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'arduinodb'
});
var count =false;

connection.connect();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  connection.query('SELECT * from Patient', function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {

      res.render('index', { title: result});
     console.log('The solution is: ', result);

    }
    else {
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    }
```

and here the HTML page(index.ejs) where i want to use the "title" array values inside the script to fill the "data" array for the chart

```
<script src='/javascripts/Chart.min.js'></script>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="buyers" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
<br>

<script>

  var buyerData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets : [
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
        strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
        pointColor : "#fff",
        pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
        data : [ 87,156,99,251,305,247]
      }
    ]
  }
  var buyers = document.getElementById('buyers').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData);
</script>
```

So, if i tried to use "title" directly , nothing would show up in the page(blank page).
Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code if your data from database is array of int:

```
<script src='/javascripts/Chart.min.js'></script>

  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="buyers" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
<br>

<script>

  var buyerData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June"],
    datasets : [
      {
        fillColor : "rgba(172,194,132,0.4)",
        strokeColor : "#ACC26D",
        pointColor : "#fff",
        pointStrokeColor : "#9DB86D",
        data : [<%= title %>]        //here 
      }
    ]
  }
  var buyers = document.getElementById('buyers').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(buyers).Line(buyerData);
</script>
```

If your data is not an array need to be mapped, eg. using lodash map:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

         connection.query('SELECT * from Patient', function(err, result) {
                     if (!err) {

                         var data = .map(result, function(n) { //here using lodash
                             return n.id;
                         });

                         res.render('index', {
                             title: data
                         });
                         console.log('The solution is: ', result);

                     } else {
                         console.log('Error while performing Query.');
                     }
```